# Jackson: is it possible to replace the serializer set with @JsonSerialize annotation (e.g. with ObjectMapper)?

Tags: json, jackson, spring-security-oauth2

Quick question: is it possible to override `@JsonSerialize` annotation (`using` attribute) with ObjectMapper?

I'm have `spring-security-oauth2` integrated and I want to customize the way `OAuth2Exception` is serialized to JSON format. The problem is that this class uses

```
@JsonSerialize(using = OAuth2ExceptionJackson2Serializer.class)
```

I tried registering custom serializer with:

```
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule()
module.addSerializer(OAuth2Exception, new JsonSerializer<OAuth2Exception>() {
    @Override
    void serialize(OAuth2Exception value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeString('{"test":"test"}')
    }
})

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
objectMapper.registerModule(module)
```

but it didn't work - the serializer set with `@JsonSerialize` is used instead of the custom one.

Is there any other way to replace the serializer set with `@JsonSerialize`?

PS: the sample code is written in `groovy`

Comment: Maybe mix-in annotations could help... Check this out: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For such case Jackson has a mechanism called [mix-in annotations](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations).

You can create a class that overrides initial annotations.

```
@JsonSerialize(using=MySerializer.class)
public static abstract class OAuth2ExceptionMixIn {

}
```

Then register it in the object mapper:

```
objectMapper.addMixIn(OAuth2Exception.class, OAuth2ExceptionMixIn.class);
```

And that's it. Now Jackson should use your `MySerializer` instead of the initial  `OAuth2ExceptionJackson2Serializer`
.

Comment: One more hint: you can even drop your custom serializer and control the serialization entirely through the mixin. Whatever you prefer.

Comment: @LukaszWiktor is it possible to take the complete programtic control over the response using just mixins without customserializer?

Comment: @Kalinga it depends on what your desired output format is. Jackoson provides many options to shape the output JSON structure - you can rename fields with `@JsonProperty`, ignore some of them with `@JsonIgnore` and do more fine-tuning `@JsonSerializer` plus `converter`. I rarely had to write a custom serializer. If you have a specific use case just post a question and let me know.

Comment: based on your answer, I have used custom serializer. It works. Just wanted to check whether there are more options other than ignore & property. Thanks anyways